# Symfony2 access control redirects to login

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle, access-control

In an application I am developing, I'm having a weird issue with the access control for the security component.

I use the FOSUserBundle (of course) for users and I copied the example access control rules from the bundle documentation to my `security.yml` The login screen (`/login`) works perfectly but the issue is, all other access control rules have absolutely no effect whatsoever. When a user goes to `/register` for example, he is redirected to `/login`, the same goes for `/resetting`.

This is my `security.yml` file:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(\_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            anonymous: false
            form_login: false
            provider: fos_userbundle
            http_basic:
                realm: "REST Service Realm"

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    ~
            switch_user:  { role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, parameter: _impersonate }

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/superadmin/, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

I have tried to turn of security for paths containing `/resetting` and `/register`, but that clearly won't work since the security token still needs to be available for the FOSUserBundle controllers.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: path: ^/register isn't enouth for detect the register and resettings pages ?

Comment: Oh, yes, it should be, the `path: ^/register(.*)` is something I changed to try and get it to work. Originally it was `path: ^/register` indeed. I'll edit my original question.

Comment: you use dev env ? the cache is clear ?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the dev environment and just tried clearing my cache but it didn't help.

Comment: See my own answer, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that another bundle was messing with each request checking if the user was logged in or not. If the user wasn't logged in, a redirect response was generated to the login page.

No idea why this was done, I think it comes from an era where the original authors had less experience with Symfony.

But so it proves again, **always** check the logs. Very thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be to do with the order of the access_control, try putting superadmin above the others. You also don't seem to have a secured_area section (like this example from [Symfony2 access control redirects to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930157/symfony2-access-control-redirects-to-login/21930558#21930558))

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried putting the `superadmin` above the other, but to no avail! Also, my `main` firewall is almost the same as your `secured_area` firewall, so I don't think that's the problem but it's worth a try! __EDIT__: Nope, no effects when replacing the `main` with a `secured_area`.

Comment: oh yes sorry I see you have used 'main' instead of 'secured_area'

have you tried flushing your cache after making the changes as well? I might be wrong but I think that would be necessary after security changes

Comment: Just tried, both with the console and by hand, but it also doesn't work. Could it be that another bundle is messing with the firewall?

Comment: I don't see why it should do because all the security should be controlled from that one security.yml file

Comment: I'd imagine it is a matter of ordering the lines correctly as I believe it is quite fussy about ordering. Maybe try reading over the documentation I sent really slowly and making sure that every single line is positioned above or below other lines correctly

Comment: I found the problem! Apparently it _was_ another bundle messing with the request and redirecting to the login page when a user is authenticated anonymously (no idea why, that should've been done in the access control rules...). Thanks for the help anyway!